# How can I modify the default color of bar figures in an OHLC chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, trading, candlestick-chart, lightningchart

I am using LightningChartJS to create an OHLC chart. The bar figures have red and green color by default. How can I change the color of these bar figures?
How do I add fill style to

```
.setPositiveStyle( (figure) => figure
                    .setStrokeStyle( (stroke) => stroke.setThickness(2) )
                   )
  .setNegativeStyle( (figure) => figure
                    .setStrokeStyle( (stroke) => stroke.setThickness(2) )
                   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the body of a OHLC figure by using the *setBodyFillStyle* method.

```
const series = chart.addOHLCSeries()
// Style a positive OHLC figure
series.setPositiveStyle( (figure) => figure
    // Style the body of a Positive Figure
    .setBodyFillStyle( new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#E69965')})
)
// Style a negative OHLC figure
series.setNegativeStyle( (figure) => figure
    // Style the body of a Negative Figure
    .setBodyFillStyle( new SolidFill({color: ColorHEX('#E659A5')})
)
```